# Hibernate Filters with JPA EntityManagerFactory and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-filters

I have a jersey + spring application that is using EntityManagerFactory and spring JpaTransactionManager to handle the db manipulations. The JPA implementation is hibernate.

I would like to know is there a way to enable hibernate filters in this scenario.

I tried extending org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager and overriding

```
@Override
protected EntityManager createEntityManagerForTransaction() {
    EntityManager manager = super.createEntityManagerForTransaction();

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    return manager;
}
```

But I am not sure that this method is called at the right place.

EDIT:
I am using spring JpaRepositories to persist/query entities.

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this?

Comment: I jsut posted the solution

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer for this problem. It seems like other people are still struggling with this, I will post my solution.

I am enabling the filters that I need in business service methods that are marked as @Transactional (that is important).

In your service, inject the entity manager factory:

```
 @Autowired
 private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

Inside the @Transactional method obtain the entity manager from the transactionManager, unwrap it to hibernate session and enable the filters that you need. This is done as follows:

```
    //Obtain the entity manager for the current transaction
    EntityManagerHolder holder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(entityManagerFactory);
    EntityManager entityManager = holder.getEntityManager();

    //Unwrap to get the underlying hibernate session
    Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    //Configure your filters
    Filter publishedAfterFilter = hibernateSession.enableFilter("...");
    publishedAfterFilter.setParameter("...", ...);
    publishedAfterFilter.validate();
```

Comment: Deyan, thanks for the post, I spent a long time looking for this, but can this be accomplished with being inside the @Transactional method?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want your method to be transactional? You can always extract whatever code you have in a separate transactional method. The thing I have described relies on the fact that the TransactionSynchronizationManager keeps the current transaction entity manager in a thread local  field. If you could give more details I may be able to help.